# hibernate IllegalArgumentException in joined-subclass with Composite key

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm, hibernate-mapping

Edit #2 - Added person class at bottom.

This is driving me nuts! I think this is a mapping problem, but I'm not sure. I'm new to Hibernate and I think using a joined-subclass with composite key is messing me up.

The error happens when I open a session and the message is:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException:
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dave.test.Person.personId
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
at com.mkyong.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:21)

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling
getter of com.dave.test.Person.personId
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get 
(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:198)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:172)
... 11 more
```

First mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.mkyong.stock.Appointment" table="appointment" catalog="physdb">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.dave.test.AppointmentId">
        <key-property name="personId" type="int">
            <column name="person_id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="apptdate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="apptdate" length="19" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="client" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="person_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="location" type="string">
        <column name="location" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="fee" type="big_decimal">
        <column name="fee" precision="7" />
    </property>
    <property name="paid" type="big_decimal">
        <column name="paid" precision="7" />
    </property>
    <property name="serviceRendered" type="boolean">
        <column name="service_rendered" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And second mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.dave.test.Person" table="person" catalog="physdb">
    <id name="personId" >
        <column name="person_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="first_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="last_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="phone" type="string">
        <column name="phone" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="cellPhone" type="string">
        <column name="`cell_phone`" length="15" />
    </property>

    <joined-subclass name="com.dave.test.Client" table="client" extends="Person">
            <key column="person_id" />
    <set name="appointments" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key column="person_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.dave.test.Appointment"/>
    </set>      

    <property name="complaint" type="string">
        <column name="complaint" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="notes" type="string">
        <column name="notes" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="doctor" type="string">
        <column name="doctor" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    </joined-subclass>

<joined-subclass name="com.dave.test.Therapist" table="therapist" extends="Person">
            <key column="person_id" />

    <property name="school" type="string">
        <column name="school" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="specialties" type="string">
        <column name="notes" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="hiredate" type="date">
        <column name="hiredate" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</joined-subclass>


 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The classes are:

```
public class Client extends Person implements java.io.Serializable {

private int personId;
private Person person;
private String complaint;
private String notes;
private String doctor;
private Set appointments = new HashSet();
public int getPersonId() {
    return this.personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

}

public class Appointment implements java.io.Serializable {

private AppointmentId id;
private Client client;
private String location;
private BigDecimal fee;
private BigDecimal paid;
private boolean serviceRendered;

public AppointmentId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(AppointmentId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}

public class AppointmentId implements java.io.Serializable {

private int personId;
private Date apptdate;

public int getPersonId() {
    return this.personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

}

public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

private int personId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phone;
private String cellPhone;
private Therapist therapist;
private Client client;


public int getPersonId() {
    return this.personId;
}

public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}
}
```

I'm sure I'm going to kick myself when I figure this out, but could someone give me a hand?
Thanks
Dave

Comment: Please provide the `Person` class contents.

Comment: Good idea! I edited the post and added the person class at the bottom.

Comment: Looks like you left out the Person class declaration and the private attributes (those were the ones I was after).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe you could provide a little project with the minimal configuration that reproduces the problem / exception (the classes, the mapping files, the configuration). You can use a free hosting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, `Client` class contains the `personId` attribute (plus getter and setter). Since `Client` extends `Person`, it inherits the `personId` property. So the one in the `Client` class should be removed.

Second thing, `Client` class contains a reference to a `Person`, which, unless the client has another `Person` (has-a, not is-a), I think is wrong and may be causing problems (although is not mapped in the XML).

Comment: Good points, I changed client and eliminated the personId getter and setter as well as the Person reference but still get the same error :                                                             2012-07-21_10:59:19.121 ERROR o.h.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.dave.test.Person, getter method of property: personId
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dave.test.Person.personId
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: My comment above did not format well, so short reply is the fixes did not work.

Comment: @Dave I can't reproduce the problem using the code you provided - it works with no exception. You need to provide a minimal set of source code that reproduces the problem (try in a separate project).

Comment: Nicolae, thanks for the suggestions. I went back and redid the project, basically from scratch, and it now works. One of these days when I'm bored out of mind maybe I'll go back and try and figure out where the mistake was.